# Как автоматически загружать файлы на диск?

Tags: google-colaboratory

У меня есть код который создает файлы (Я не могу поменять папку в самом коде так как код не мой)
и мне нужно проверять папку на изменения если в папке существует новый файл то копировать его на мой гугл диск
Есть ли в гугл колабе инструменты для этого?
Или можно ли как-то синхронизировать только папку где создаются файлы с моим диском